# JQuery hide/show not working on controls on a modal display

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2 in VS 2019 and Bootstrap version 2.

I have a modal form and the CSHTML code to display it is:

```
<div id="modalSiblingDetails" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="modalSiblingDetailsLabel" aria-hidden="true">    
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DummySibling.DoBSiblinig, new { @class = "CDOPDoBSibling" })
        <div id="CDOPDummyAgeOfSiblingDisplay">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DummySibling.AgeOfSibling)
        </div>        
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-default closeModalForm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary modalContactDetailsClose" id="modalContactDetailsConfirm">
                Add details
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-sibling", function () {        
        $("#modalSiblingDetails").modal({ "backdrop": "static" });
        $("#CDOPDummyAgeOfSiblingDisplay").hide();
        $(document).on("change", ".CDOPDoBSibling:visible", function () {
            console.log($("#CDOPDummyAgeOfSiblingDisplay").is('visible'));
            $("#CDOPDummyAgeOfSiblingDisplay").show();
            //SetCDOPDoBSibling(this);
        });
    });
```

I want to hide and show the div `CDOPDummyAgeOfSiblingDisplay` depending on an event on the modal. My problem is that the div does not hide or show. I use this method elsewhere but not on a modal form.

The change event is being called and the console log always shows false. If I move the initial hide to before the modal display the hide works.

How do I hide/show the div?

Comment: Better to copy html from browser so that the issue you mention can be reproduced.

Comment: Bootstrap 2?? Did I read that right? It's been [out of support](https://github.com/twbs/release) for _a decade_.

Comment: @isherwood Fraid so - it is version 2 - not by choice but lack of resource to upgrade. It's a large app

Comment: @KiranShahi It's a complex app so grabbing meaningful HTML not straightforward. Currently working on an alternate solution but wondered if there were an obvious solution to this situation.

Comment: I understand, but a handful of search-and-replace commands gets you 99% of the way to Bootstrap 5. It would be worth doing, if only for better community support.

Comment: Hi, what event trigger `CDOPDoBSibling` to show ? Are you clicking on some button ?

Comment: @Swati Yes, clicking on a button

Comment: Resolved (rather than solved) the problem. It appears that the modal was nested too deeply in the form. Now working correclly,